# BizTalk 2013 Getting xml content in map

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-2013r2

How can I get the XML context (the entire Msg) using a map, from the source schema, and pass it to an element field in the destination schema?

Scenario Description: The Msg was previously received (already in MsgBox). The map is located in a SendPort of type WFC-Custom with SqlBinding. The idea is to storage the entire XML Msg into a Database table field of type XML.

I'm not using any Orchestration on this application, on BizTalk 2013 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a script functoid and write a inline xslt like below

```
<xsl:element name="tgtXml">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
<xsl:copy-of select="/" />
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: This recommendation worked out as expected. I ended on using a similar approach (Below). Thank you so much.

<xsl:template name="called-template">
  <xsl:param name="param1" />
  <xsl:element name="ns0:YourElementNameHere">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="identity" match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>